# How to evaluate two function in one statement?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, vb.net

How to declare two object in one statement for vb.net?
example

> If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text),(TextBox2.Text) Then 
>    lbl_answer.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox2.Text) 
>     Else 
>               MsgBox("Error only number can be calculate") 
>           End If

I can do

> if isnumeric(textbox1.text) then

but I can't say

> if isnumeric(textbox1.text), (textbox2.text)

How can I do so?

Comment: try the `And` operator.

`If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) And IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) Then`

Comment: What desaivv said. Wanted to add that what you are doing isn't declaring two objects, but evaluating two functions.

Comment: Or the VB.net equivalent of `new[]{TextBox1.Text,TextBox2.Text}.All(IsNumeric)`

Comment: why people vote down? when someone asking for something he don't know.

Comment: @SbSangpi - The question was down-voted on Programmers because you were asking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nobody did so far let me express your options (straight from the comments - sorry but why those are not answers I don't know):

1. `And`

   ```
   If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) And IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) Then ...
   ```
2. `AndAlso` (subtle difference: `AndAlso` don't evaluate the second expression if the first evaluates to false)

   ```
   If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) AndAlso IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) Then ...
   ```

I don't think the LINQ one is really a option.